# NServicebus hierarchy and structure

Tags: nservicebus, soa, esb

I am just starting out learning NServicebus (and SOA in general) and have a few questions and points I need clarification on regarding how the solution is typically structured and common best practices:

1. The documentation doesn't really explain what an endpoint is.  From what I gather it is a unit of 
   deployment and your service will have 1 or more endpoints.  Is this correct?
2. Is it considered best practice to have one VS solution per Service you are developing?  With a project for messages, then a project for each endpoint, and finally a project that is shared with the endpoints containing your domain layer?
3. From what I read, services are usually comprised of individual components.  Can (or should) any component in the service access the same database, or should it be one database per component?

Thanks for any clarification or insight one can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try and answer your questions the best i can...

I'm not sure about the term "Best Practices" i would consider the term "Best Thinking" or "Paradigm"

Q1: yes, an endpoint is a effectively a deployed process that consumes the messages of it's queue.

It's dose not have to belong to a single "Service" (logical) (In the case of a web endpoint for example), an endpoint can have one or more handlers deployed to it.

Q2: I would go with one solution (and later repo) per logical domain service, Inside a solution I would create a project per message handler, because as you scale you will need to move you handler between endpoints, or to their own endpoint depending on scale. Messages however are contracts, so i would put them in a solution/s maybe split commands and events. You may consider something like nuget to publish your message packages.

Q3: A "Service" is a logical composition of autonomous components, each is a vertical slice of functionality, so they can share the same database, but i would say that only one component has the authority to modify it's own data. I would always try to think what would happen when you need to scale.

Dose this make sense?

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't go as far as creating a separate project per message handler. Sounds like a bit of a premature optimization. You can split out related handlers into separate projects when the need comes.

Comment: Agreed--good answer, and I also agree that one project per handler could get out of control really fast.  Having our message assembly (or assemblies) published to a local nuget server removes a TON of friction for consuming projects.

Comment: This clears up a lot for me.  I also like the tip about the local nuget package for messages.  Thanks!